# Sequence Diagrams ARGOUML

Tags: java, uml, sequence-diagram, argouml

Im having trouble using argoUML to draw  my squence diagrams. Does anyone know how I can generate a sequence diagram in argouml?

Comment: Could you describe what problem you are having or where you are stuck?  I'm familiar with ArgoUML sequence diagrams, but it's unclear what problem you are having.

Comment: I had the same question. Didn't see any useful tutorials on YouTube in English. I ended up making my sequence diagram with: http://www.websequencediagrams.com/

Comment: Interesting. I (tried to) use ArgoUML some 20 years ago and it was sort of a zombie program. 5 years after reporting a bug someone took care. You might consider looking for a different tool.

Answer (score 0):

The best tool for sequence diagrams I ever found is Quick Sequence Diagram Editor - check it out: http://sdedit.sourceforge.net/index.html

Comment: That doesn't answer the question that was asked.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use other tools, I used http://www.websequencediagrams.com/ which gave me what I needed.

I liked the fact that I don't have to download an executable, it generate the images in real time and I can save the text that generated the diagram (I can also right click and save the generated image as well).

Comment: That doesn't answer the question that was asked.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the webstart version of argouml. And if you problem is not even able to create a sequence diagram. Please try download one instead of start it via webstart.

My locally installed copy have no trouble creating sequence diagram, while the webstarted one can't.

Comment: +1 for a useful answer. I don't know why this answer had been downvoted, because it's the only correct answer to the question which had been asked. Other answers propose a usage of other tools, so they actually don't answer the question. In my case the zipped binary package worked correctly, so that I could create a sequence diagram, though the setup and Java Web Start versions didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the zipped binary package worked correctly, so that I could create a sequence diagram, though the setup and Java Web Start versions didn't work.

Here's the link to a [binary package of the latest stable version](http://argouml-downloads.tigris.org/nonav/argouml-0.34/ArgoUML-0.34.zip). 
Here's a link to the [page with all available downloads for the last stable version](http://argouml-downloads.tigris.org/argouml-0.34/)